# What is the difference between at and operator[] in a const method?

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map

I'm writing an assignment and I ran into some issue
using the following unordered_map:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, Account*> m_accounts_map;
```

Compiles without errors:

```
const Account& Bank::getBankAccount(const std::string ID) const
{
    return *m_accounts_map.at(ID);
}
```

Does not compiles:

```
const Account& Bank::getBankAccount(const std::string ID) const
{
    return *m_accounts_map[ID];
}
```

The above code generate the following compilation error:

> error: passing 'const std::unordered_map, Account*>' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

But when I remove the `const` it compiles:

```
const Account& Bank::getBankAccount(const std::string ID)
{
    return *m_accounts_map[ID];
}
```

According to [std::unordered_map::operator[]](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/operator[]/) 
the difference is:

> A similar member function, unordered_map::at, has the same behavior when an element with the key exists, but throws an exception when it does not.

But that's does not explain this behavior.
I don't understand why dose `operator[]` discards qualifiers.

So what is the subtle differences I'm not aware of?

Comment: What does `operator[]` do if the value **doesn't** exist?

Comment: What part of the error message did you not understand?

Comment: _"But when I remove the it compiles:"_ missed a word?

Comment: Prefer [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at) to that site.

Comment: This is the second worst design flaw in the C++ Standard Library IMHO, after the `bool` specialisation for `std::vector`.

Comment: @Bathsheba - Should be the other way around?

Comment: IMO this is an excellent design decision and makes common use cases for a map have easy syntax